# Angular library with Storybook debugging in vscode not working

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, storybook

There are a lot of articles online about debugging storybook, Angular and vscode but none quite tackle my issue (I think) but I have tried all the recommended changes in them anyway without any luck.

I have Angular workbook with a single library in it. I have then installed/initialised storybook which puts the storybook "application" inside the library (i.e. the .storybook folder with the configuration files and a 'stories' folder).

Initially I thought this was wrong and tried other configurations only to realise that this default configuration is correct and works the best as it loads all of the component code, auto refreshes on code changes, has access to all of the component members etc.

I have turned on sourceMaps in EVERY tsconfig file including the one in the .storybook folder.

I have the following launch.json (although I have tried other configs too)

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome for Storybook",
  "url": "http://localhost:6006",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

If I set a breakpoint it may stop on it randomly and not when I expect (i.e. the source maps seem wrong) or sometimes it breaks in the *.iframe.bundle.js file!

I can't seem to find the typescript files in the browser dev tools either otherwise I would use those. I feel like I must have something really wrong?

Also when I try to add the sourceMap option in my angular.json file it says it's not allowed!

Answer (score 0):

So I thought come back and admit to my own stupidity just in case someone else is battling with this.

Sourcemaps were not turned on by default in my workspace angular.json so I added set sourceMaps to try for my storybook build in angular.json (i.e. not my production one):

```
"storybook": {
      "builder": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
        "configDir": "projects/ui-lib/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "ui-lib:build",
        "compodoc": true,
        "compodocArgs": ["-e", "json", "-d", "projects/ui-lib"],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "projects/cpx-ui-lib/src/styles/theme.scss"
        ],
        "assets": ["projects/cpx-ui-lib/src/assets"],
        "port": 6006,
        "sourceMap": true
      }
    }
```

And then just made sure I launched my Chrome debug instance as normal from VS Code. My launch.json config is below for reference:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome for Storybook",
      "url": "http://localhost:6006",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I can just hit F5 or press the debug play button and everything works.